# Creating External Table in Hive using HIVE JDBC : Not Possible?

Tags: jdbc, hive

External Table creation via `HIVE JDBC` isnt reflected in the hive datawarehouse whereas the normal table creation inside the hive datawarehouse happens without any issue.

After creating the table via Hive JDBC,

```
stmt.executeQuery("create external table trial (TOPIC STRING) row format delimited fields terminated by '' STORED as TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/ranjitha/trial'");`
```

no error returned.

But when I try retrieving from this table trial, nothing is returned.

Here in this link, https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cdh-user/YTekdFtbelE, it says external table creation not possible using `HIVE JDBC`.

It would be really helpful if someone can guide me on the above. Is this not possible with JDBC or is there another alternative for the same.

Thanks